# What was the project file type of Visual C++ back in the 1990s?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

Is there anyone out there who remembers what was the file extension used by Microsoft Visual C++ way back in early days (1995-1998 or so) to hold a C++ ***project***?  This would be around the days of Visual C++ 5.0/6.0, I think

(Currently, they use `.vcxproj` but it's changed a few times over the years.)

I just found a disc with stuff I worked on back then that I'd like to build.  I see the .H, .CPP, .RC files, etc. but nothing resembling a *project* file.   None of the following extensions exist anywhere in the source tree: `.dsp`, `.sln`, `.mdp` `.vcproj`, `.vcxproj`

I do see a `.MAK` file but I seem to recall never using it back then and instead doing everything through the IDE.  I don't know if my memory is faulty or not. Wasn't there some other project file extension in use around then?

(If I must, I can just create a project around this source, but I think this thing had some custom build steps in the project which I'd like to look at)

Comment: VC6 used `.dsp` for the project and `.dsw` for the solution (known as "workspace", hence `w`).

Comment: Ah ok, then I guess for whatever reason, the project files have been removed.   I wasn't the last one to work on this so maybe they came up with a makefile-based build procedure.  Thank you!

Comment: The "Open Project" dialogue in VS19 also lists .vcp and .vdp as known extensions.

Comment: @Joe VC6 supported projects of type "external makefile". Many projects ported from 16-bit used this type back then, with makefiles named `<APPNAME>.MAK` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Very early (1995) versions of C++ were released under the name "Visual C++ Workbench" there was **only one file** created for the project. Both versions 1.52 and 2.0 used an extension ".mak".

[image: This is how it looked then]

Comment: Oddly enough I do remember that.  I started off with version 2.0 (maybe 2.1 or 2.2?) on Windows NT.  But I thought (maybe wrongly) that by the time we got to 5.0/6.0 it was all their custom project file format.  I didn't recall that there was an option to still use .MAK by then.  I guess after I was done with this project, the people who worked on it after me switched over the .MAK format because I know I never would have done that.   I hated make files.  Impressed you've still got this version (in the image) running somewhere...

Comment: MAK in both versions of the Visual Workbench was the only format that was used. Later versions added dsw as is the workspace file and dsp as the project file, with the ability to build using mak files that were generated by the VS. 1.52 version was 16-bit development (Windows 3) and version 2 for 32-bit development - (Windows NT).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 6 uses two files, .dsp and .dsw.

The .dsp file is the project but doesn't store what files were open, etc., so VC6 chides you for trying to double click that file and instead recommends the .dsw (workspace) file.  I'm pretty sure that VC5 used the same pair of files, but cannot check.

[image: Don't use the .DSP file!]